# IIS and Zend url rewrite

Tags: php, zend-framework, iis, url-rewriting

I am having issues with IIS. I can't seem to access www.site.com/controller/method
In my Zend project folder I have:

```
-public
-application
-...
-web.config
```

web.config content (to point to the public/ folder):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 14" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="!\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 15" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And in my **public/** folder I have the following config (found in the Zend documentation):

web.config content:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*$" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I think the main issue is **rule 14** but I don't know why it doesn't work, and there is *no impact if I delete the config from the public folder*.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be very helpful, this is my first deployment on a Windows server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `Imported Rule 14` to be as follow:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 14" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The option `!` doesn't work in this case so use `negate="true"` instead.